# Interpolating between disks in the plane

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, plane-geometry

Below, a "disk" means a compact subspace $D \subset \mathbb R^2$ whose boundary is a smooth simple closed curve.

> **Task:** Find a procedure which takes as input a pairs
> of disks
> $
> D_0 \subseteq D_1
> $
> in the plane,
> and produces as output a smooth 1-parameter family of disks that interpolates between them:
> $$
> \{D_t\}_{t \in [0,1]}.
> $$
> The family should be monotonic in the sense that
> $
> t_1 \le t_2 \Rightarrow D_{t_1} \subseteq D_{t_2}.
> $

The procedure should furthermore be (continuous and) smooth, meaning that if we have a family of pairs $D_0(x) \subseteq D_1(x)$ depending smoothly on some parameter $x\in\mathbb R^n$, then the output of the procedure $\{D_t(x)\}_{t \in [0,1]}$ should depend smoothly on $(t,x)\in [0,1]\times\mathbb R^n$.

---

**Remark:** If $D_0$ is contained in the interior of $D_1$, then the level curves of the solution of the Dirichlet problem on $D_1 {\setminus} \mathring D_0$ with boundary values $0$ on $\partial D_0$ and $1$ on $\partial D_1$ provide a family of simple closed curves interpolating between $\partial D_0$ and $\partial D_1$ (hence a family of disks interpolating between $D_0$ and $D_1$). This procedure has all the desired good properties, but it doesn't obviously work when $\partial D_0 \cap \partial D_1 \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: I did not understand why the procedure outlined in the Remark does not work. The difference $D_1\backslash D_0$ is not necessarily connected in this case, but this does not prevent you from solving Dirichlet problem for each component and using the level lines for your "move".

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko. Yes, in that way, you will produce a family of disks with  piecewise smooth boundary. Is their boundary smooth? Maybe it is. If you know how to prove the smoothness of your construction, please do tell me how the argument goes.

Comment: This feels like a very hard problem that should be more famous than it is... I recall David Epstein worked/works on this question... and said that it related it to Teichmuller theory, to computer vision, to other things... I will try to find a reference.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but it seems to me that the construction in the Remark gives you curves which are at least as smooth as the worse one of $D_1,D_0$. What do you exactly mean by "smooth"? $C^k$? $C^\infty$?

Comment: My argument is this: at all points except those of $\partial D_1\cap\partial D_0$ those level lines are real analytic. For points $\in\partial D_0\cap\partial D_1$, use the simple fact that if a function $f$ satisfies $g(x)<f(x)<h(x)$ and at $x_0$ all three are equal, then $f$ has at least as many derivatives as $g,h$ have at $x_0$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko. If $\partial_0 \cap \partial _1$ is a single point, then the higher derivatives of your two functions $$ and $ℎ$ need not agree (by "smooth", I mean $^\infty$). And even if the all the higher derivatives of $$
 and $ℎ$ agree, there's still something to show: for example, how do you know that the higher derivatives of $$ are bounded? (I'm sure they are – I just don't know how to prove it)

Comment: By a "procedure," you don't necessarily mean a computer algorithm, do you? An existence proof would be good enough? It's not clear to me how to represent an arbitrary $D$ on a computer.

Comment: @TimothyChow By "procedure" I mean "smooth map". I need a smooth map from the space of pairs of discs to the space of 1-parameter families of disks (and the exact meaning of 'smooth' is spelled out in my question). I'd be completely happy if you could prove the existence of such a procedure/map without actually specifying/constructing one.

Comment: Presumably a two-stage process would not satisfy your needs? Shrink $D_0$ until it fits strictly inside $D_1$, and then apply the level-curves process.

Comment: The Dirichlet problem for touching circles involves boundary multivalued boundary values at the intersection. Does this make sense? You could think of it as the Dirichlet problem on a noncompact manifold. Does this have a unique solution? Probably not, but perhaps a canonical solution.

Comment: The solution to the Dirichlet problem has long distance dependence on the shape of the curves. But if you have two contact points and a disconnected domain, there cannot be information sent between the two regions. Thus for this approach to work it is necessary for the Taylor series of the interpolating curves at the contact to depend only on the Taylor series of the original curves there. If this is true, it might be easy to prove.

Comment: @BenWieland: You are absolutely correct. I think it's plausible that the Taylor series of the interpolating curves at the contact (exist and) only depend on the Taylor series of the original curves there. Any guess what that dependence might be?

Comment: I suppose it might be helpful to note that, if we pull back $D_1$ by a conformal mapping $f$ (and using the fact that a disk with smooth curve has such a map $f$ which is smooth across the boundary, and similarly for its inverse), we may as well be assuming $D_1$ is the unit disk. There's a few classes of "canonical" families of univalent mappings in function theory, maybe one of them suffices...

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: Sadly a two-stage process does not satisfy my needs.

Comment: @BenJohnsrude. Yes, I was aware of that, and I think it's a good idea. But I don't know how to use it to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an incomplete approach that was too long for a comment.

1. In some smooth way, choose $\epsilon>0$ such that

   (i) the region $C_\epsilon\subset \overline{D_1}$ within distance $\epsilon$ of $\partial D_1$ is a collar neighbourhood of $\partial D_1$ (i.e. there is a smooth embedding $\phi:\partial D_1 \times [0,\epsilon) \to C$ such that $\phi(x,t)$ is the point in $C$ at distance $t$ along the normal $\nu_x$ to $\partial D_1$ at $x$),

   (ii) $C_\epsilon \cap \partial D_0$ is the set $\{\phi(x,u(x)):x \in V_\epsilon\}$ for some set $V_\epsilon \subset \partial D_1$ and smooth function $u:V_\epsilon \to [0,\epsilon)$, and

   (iii) $|\nabla u|<\tilde{\epsilon}$ on $V_\epsilon$ for some $\tilde{\epsilon}>0$.
2. Let $\eta\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ be a smooth function with $\eta=0$ on $(-\infty,0)$ and $\eta=1$ on $[1,\infty)$. For some $0<\delta<\epsilon$, let $\tilde{D}_0 \subset D_1$ be the set such that
   $$
   \partial \tilde{D}_0 \cap C_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}
   =\left\{\phi\left(x,\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\left(u(x)-\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)\eta\left(\frac{2u(x)}{\epsilon}\right)\right):x \in V_\epsilon, u(x)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right\},
   $$
   and $\tilde{D}_0 \backslash C_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}=D_0 \backslash C_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}$. Then $\tilde{D}_0$ has smooth boundary and $\partial \tilde{D}_0 \cap \partial D_1=\emptyset$.
3. Let $w \in C^\infty(D_1 \backslash \tilde{D}_0$ denote the solution to the Dirichlet problem on $D_1 \backslash \tilde{D}_0$ with boundary conditions $w=0$ on $\partial \tilde{D}_0$ and $w=1$ on $\partial D_1$. I believe, but have no proof, that by choosing $\epsilon,\tilde{\epsilon}$ small enough, we can ensure that for each $x \in V_\epsilon$, $s \mapsto w(\phi(x,s))$ is increasing for $s \in (0,u(x))$. For $t \in (0,1)$ and $x \in V_x$, let $u_t(x)$ denote the distance from $x$ to $w^{-1}(s)$ along $\nu_x$.
4. Define $D_t$ such that $D_t \backslash C_\epsilon$ is the $t$-superlevel set of $w$ in $D_1 \backslash C_\epsilon$, and
   $$
   \partial D_t \cap C_\epsilon=\left\{\left(x, u_t(x) + \left(t u(x) - u_t(x)\right) \eta\left(\frac{2u(x)}{\epsilon}-1\right)\right):x \in V_x \right\}.
   $$
   That is, $D_t$ moves linearly from $D_0$ to $D_1$ within $C_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}$, $D_t$ is a level set of $w$ on $D_1 \backslash C_\epsilon$. Also, $D_t$ is smooth, and on $C_\epsilon$ (as well as on $D_1 \backslash C_\epsilon$), the $D_t$ are correctly nested since $u_t(x) + \left(t u(x) - u_t(x)\right) \eta\left(\frac{2u(x)}{\epsilon}-1\right)$ is increasing in $t$.

Hopefully, someone more familiar with the Dirichlet problem can show that the solution to the DIrichlet problem on a thin enough strip has gradients which are never parallel to the strip.

Comment: This looks promising.